# What are the necessary fields to provide in a CSV so that the orders are created properly?

Tags: 8, commerce

In the context of Drupal 8 and Commerce 2, I need to create about 1000 orders on behalf of my users.

What are the necessary fields to provide in a CSV so that the orders are created properly?

- The store, products, and payment gateways are all set up and work as expected
- I have a view set up to export sample orders so I can see field syntax and values
- I'm intending to use Feeds to import the master CSV

I assume we will need at least OrderNum, Date, Type, Customer, Email, State, Total, OrderItems, PaymentGateway, Placed, TotalPaid, and TotalPaid (currency_code), but this is guesswork.

Is there a schema or other sort of definition I can use?

I am definitely trying to avoid custom modules and other programmatic approaches (as outlined in similar questions).

Comment: Hey boabjohn, while we definitely would love to help you to get this up and running, it's kind of a too broad question. Then you say you want to avoid programmatic custom module solutions. Means you are asking for a tutorial for a third-party dependency, which both are off-topic for Drupal Answers. So that's too broad and off-topic at once. You need to come up with a narrowly scoped and reproducible problem (as in steps to reproduce included). That's what Drupal Answers is for.

Comment: Greetings @leymannx, I do appreciate the ethos of precise, targetted quesions. In this case I am looking NOT for a tutorial, I am looking for a pointer to something that *I think* ought to exist already, ie, a specification for the minimum fields needed to bulk create Commerce 2 orders. That is a specific query, it is not asking for help with programming, and it is not asking for help on how to use a module. I know Feeds very well, and am very comfortable with Views. If you can focus in on the core of the question, I think it will make more sense.

Comment: Commerce is a beast. I don't know it very well yet, but am pretty ok with the relationships between the various tables. If my opening idea is to bulk upload Orders, I know there are a range of field values that need to be provided. I could guess, I could spend hours trying to re-engineer the ER diagram OR I could first pose the query to this learned group and see if (a) there is indeed a reference spec like I hope for or (b) it is simply not that simple and must be done programmatically.